# bootstrap datepicker tand timepicker glyphicons not aligned properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating Date Picker and Time picker in Bootstrap 4 using bootstrap-datepicker.js and bootstrap-timepicker.js. The issue is the calendar and time icon is not displaying properly. I want them to be inside the input button but it appears down the input box.

```
<div class="col-md-3 columns">
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker">  
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 columns">
    <label>Time:</label>
    <input id="timepicker1" type="text" >
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
</div>
```

These are my CSS and Javascript files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should not use bootstrap `4.0.0-beta.2` as it is way too outdated. The current version is 4.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display buttons besides input field, you need to wrap input and button in `.input-group` class, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 columns">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>Time:</label>
    <input id="timepicker1" type="text" >
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
  </div>
```

Icons are missing, because glyphicons were removed form Bootstrap 4, so you'll need to load them separately.